# Selecting an element by ng-click in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

in our angular app there are language icons to change language:

```
<img style="cursor: pointer; margin-right: 5px; float: left;" height="25px"
 src="assets/images/english.jpg" ng-click="setLang('en')" class="">
```

How can I click on this icon with protractor? Based on other questions this should be the way:

```
element(by.css('[ng-click="setLang('en')"]')).click();
```

But this one throws a syntax error, because of the 'en' part.
So I also tried these:

```
element(by.css('[ng-click="setLang(en)"]')).click();
element(by.css('[ng-click="setLang()"]')).click();
```

But both of these resulted in: No element found using locator

Please advise how can I click on this element?

Comment: Escape quotes `'[ng-click="setLang(\'en\')"]'`

Comment: to re use it in page objects u might as well do variable
`var lenguage = 'en'` and in code use 
`element(by.css('[ng-click="setLang('en')"]')).click();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape quotes.

```
 element(by.css('[ng-click="setLang(\'en\')"]')).click();
```

Answer (score 6):

While escaping quotes might fix the immediate problem, but you should know that *partial attribute check* is also an option:

```
element(by.css('[ng-click*=setLang]')).click();
$('[ng-click*=setLang]').click();
```

where `*=` means "contains", `$` is a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! Your solution indeed also works.

`$('[ng-click*=en]').click();`

Is the right way for me as there are multiple setLang buttons, otherwise I would need to use element.all